# NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB snmpget dosnt work

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have c++ application running on Ubuntu.
I need to add support to monitoring few application scalar values by snmp.
I tried to follow the [snmp-net set tutorials](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT%3asnmpset) , but it didnt work for me.

At the end of the tutorial i run this:

```
/usr/local/sbin/snmpd -f -L -d -p 9999
```

In another terminal run this:

```
snmpget -v2c -c tutget localhost:9999 NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0
```

but i get:
   Timeout: No Response from localhost:9999.

however run this:

```
snmptranslate -Td -M+. -mNET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB -IR nstAgentModuleObject
```

return the MIB DESC.

in addtional try to run with MIB location like this, return the same.

```
snmpget -v2c -c tutget -M+ -mNET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB localhost:9999 NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0
```

Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweak the /etc/init.d/snmpd script
so that it runs the binary /usr/local/sbin/snmpd, rather than /usr/sbin/snmpd.

than i run :
/etc/init.d/snmpd start

and now it worked (without the 9999 port).

Answer (score 0):

Your `snmpget` doesn't know where to look for your MIBs. You need to add -M+/mib_dir/ to your snmpconf before you can do an explicit include of your MIB module.

Example:

snmpget -v2c -M+../mib/ -m+ALL -c tutget localhost:9999

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/snmpd -f -L -d -p 9999
```

you need root permission to setup a new port

9999 is just a temporal port, if you are not comfortable with this, just try this command

```
sudo pkill snmpd ;  sudo snmpd -LS 0-6 d
```

you need to kill the previous snmpd service before you start a new one. 
I used the net-tutorial package, so I can't use such command

```
sudo service snmpd stop
sudo service snmpd start
sudo service snmpd restart
```

but if you are using the ubuntu or Unix-like download package, you can use such command